# Exploring a file structure using php using scandir()

Tags: php, file, directory

I am new to php and trying to learn how to navigate a local file structure in for the format:

```
 -Folder
  -SubFolder
     -SubSubFolder
     -SubSubFolder
  -SubFolder
      -SubSubFolder
  ...
```

From another stackoverflow question I have been able to use this code using scandir():

```
<?php
$scan = scandir('Folder');

foreach($scan as $file)
{
    if (!is_dir($file))
    {
       $str = "Folder/".$file;
       echo $str;
    }
}
?>
```

This allows me to generate a list of strings of all the 'SubFolder' in my folder directory.

What I am trying to do is list all the 'SubSubFolder' in each 'SubFolder', so that I can create a string of the 'SubSubFolder' name in combination with its 'SubFolder' parent and add it to an array.

```
<?php
$scan = scandir('Folder');

foreach($scan as $file)
{
    if (!is_dir($file))
    {
        $str = "Folder/".$file;
        //echo $str;

        $scan2 = scandir($str);
        foreach($scan2 as $file){
            if (!is_dir($file))
            {
                echo "Folder/SubFolder/".$file;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This however isn't working, and I wasn't sure if it was because I cannot do consecutive scandir() or if I cannot use $file again.

Comment: Is it the Folder and SubFolder structure you want or do you want to include files also?

Comment: i made the edit it as it is now it is "Folder/SubFolder/".$file

I want to include the "Folder/SubFolder/SubSubFolder" in the string at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better solution, but hopefully the following will be of some help.

```
 <?php
function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){

    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' );
    // Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts
    // will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin.

    $dh = @opendir( $path );
    // Open the directory to the handle $dh

    while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){
    // Loop through the directory

        if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){
        // Check that this file is not to be ignored

            $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 4 ) );
            // Just to add spacing to the list, to better
            // show the directory tree.

            if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){
            // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down...

                echo "<strong>$spaces -$file</strong><br />";
                getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) );
                // Re-call this same function but on a new directory.
                // this is what makes function recursive.

            } else {

                //To list folders names only and not the files within comment out the following line.
                echo "$spaces $file<br />.";
                // Just print out the filename
            }
        }
    }
    closedir( $dh );
    // Close the directory handle
}
getDirectory( "folder" );
// Get the current directory
?>
```

Comment: Not exactly the solution I used, but the format is pretty much what worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using the code you supplied but couldn't get the desired outcome so decided to try a different approach hope it's of help.